# Searching a csv file for elements on a list Python

Tags: python

I need some help with a script I made in Python and it's not working.

So I have a file with some identifiers (numbers), that I turn into a list. so far so good!

Then I want to check a .csv file, and if the first element of the line is on the previous list write that line to a new .csv file.

My script looks like this:

```
tratamento = open('therapies.csv')
tratados_B = open('tratados_SubB.csv')
Outfile = open('subtype_B_Tratamento.csv', 'w')

treated_list = []


for line in tratados_B:
    TL = line.strip()
    treated_list.append(TL) 

for line in tratamento:
    TLB = line.strip().split(';')[0]
    if TLB in treated_list:
        Outfile.write(line)
    else: 
        pass
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please explain "it's not working". Also file objects are expected to be explicitly closed after accessing.

Comment: Do you've `Outfile.close()` or `Outfile.flush()` in your source code?

Comment: Basically I think it is only reading the first line, and because the first line is not on the list it does not do anything else. The output file is empty. I added the Outfile.close(), it did not change a thing.

Comment: @MEusebio There's no `break` statement in your loop, so it is going to loop through all the lines, but that `else:pass` thing is unnecessary.
Try to print `repr(TLB)` inside the loop.

Comment: Can you add example input files? Try to reduce them to a minimum, and see if you can reproduce the error. If you can, please update your answer with these.

Comment: When I put    print repr(TLB) I also get a number, but this time between ''

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `Outfile.close()` at the end of your script.

A better way of doing this is to use the `with` keyword.

```
treated_list = []

with open('subtype_B_Tratamento.csv', 'w') as Outfile,
     open('therapies.csv') as tratamento,
     open('tratados_SubB.csv') as tratados_B:

    for line in tratados_B:
        TL = line.strip()
        treated_list.append(TL) 

    for line in tratamento:
        TLB = line.strip().split(';')[0]
        if TLB in treated_list:
            Outfile.write(line)
```

`With` handles the closing of the file for you.